# SoapUI: How to retrieve Representation data with Groovy

Tags: groovy, soapui

I asked this in the eviware board but haven't received an answer. So I will try my luck here.

I have a Rest service that I am testing and I want to pull the information from the Representation tab, but I don't know how and the api isn't the easiest to read.

This is what I've been using that has giving me errors:

```
import com.eviware.soapui.impl.rest.RestRepresentation

x = RestRepresentation.getMediaType()

log.info(x)
```

And this is the error:

```
No Signature of Method: static com.eviware.soapui.impl.rest.RestRepresentation.getMediaType()
is applicable for argument types: () values: [] Possible solutions: getMediaType(),    getMediaType(java.lang.String), getSchemaType(), getType()
```

Answer (score 1):

That fails as the [`getMediaType()`](http://www.soapui.org/apidocs/com/eviware/soapui/impl/rest/RestRepresentation.html#getMediaType%28%29) method for the class [`com.eviware.soapui.impl.rest.RestRepresentation`](http://www.soapui.org/apidocs/com/eviware/soapui/impl/rest/RestRepresentation.html) is not `static`

To call `getMediaType`, you will need an instance of `RestRepresentation`

I've not used SoapUI, but it [looks like a good place to look](http://www.soapui.org/apidocs/com/eviware/soapui/impl/rest/class-use/RestRepresentation.html) would be inside the `RestRequest` object which I am guessing you have access to?

Comment: I'll try it and see what happens. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

As @tim_yates has already explained, you need an instance of `RestRepresentation`. Maybe the following code can point you in the right direction (even if the thread is very old):

```
// First, fetch the proper REST Service (Interface)
def service = testRunner.testCase.testSuite.project.getInterfaceByName('https://example.com:8090')

// Then, dig down to the REST Representations
service.operationList.each{ operation -> 
    operation.restMethodList.each{ method->
        method.representations.each{ representation->
            // Finally, do something with the instance
            // of com.eviware.soapui.impl.rest.RestRepresentation 
            log.info representation.getMediaType()
        }
    }
}
```

I have taken the snippet from one of our Groovy test steps in SoapUI 5.2.1.